# Standalone authoritative DNS server for Windows

Tags: windows, gratis, networking, dns

Similar to [Tiny single process authorative DNS server for Linux](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/4394/tiny-single-process-authoritative-dns-server-for-linux), I am looking for

- a DNS Server software
- that runs standalone (i.e. is an exe that I double click, not a service that runs in the background)
- works on Windows 7 (x64 SP1)
- is gratis
- allows commercial use
- has a UI for assigning names and IPs
- supports DNS load balancing (configure more than one IP per name; configurable whether it returns same or random order of IPs)
- ideally does not need installation (portable app)

I just need it for testing purposes, since I don't want to contact our IT department each time I want to play with the DNS settings.

I have tried:

- [SANS](http://posadis.sourceforge.net/sans), but it does not support randomizing of IP addresses. Other than that, this is basically what I'm looking for: simple UI, got it up and running within a few minutes.